# Issue in launching the application in Microsoft Edge. Some of the ajax scripts not loading at the time of page launch

Tags: java, ajax, web-applications, microsoft-edge, sessionid

Issue in launching the application in Microsoft Edge. Some of the  ajax scripts not loading  at the time of page launch.

(The application still is working as expected in Internet explorer and Firefox till today.)

In analyzing the cause of the issue , found  in the logs of application that the session (A Map object fetched via  ActionContext.getContext().getSession();) is not null at the launch of the UI page but at the later stage  this session is blanked out which is  throwing Null Pointer Exception  causing the code to break, while the same code is working in Internet explorer and Firefox. This might be due to the browser clearing the session.

Comment: Will the problem you mentioned also appear in Chrome? According to your description, do you mean that Edge cleared the session itself and caused this problem? If this is the case, have you configured to automatically clear the cache when exit Edge? If possible, please provide a minimal example that can reproduce this problem, which will help solve the problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.